# MSACCESS CODE convert to SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

hi i would like to ask for your Help i have an MSACCESS code and i want to convert it to SQL (SSMS) please see code below.

```vb
Private Sub updateDuplicateNetwork()
 Dim rstTemp As DAO.Recordset
 Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
 Dim strPIN As String
 Dim strContract As String
 Dim strNetwork As String
 Set rstTemp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qry_HR_temp_Consultant_Data_DuplicateNetwork_EachValue")
 Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_HR_Contract_Detail")
 If Not rstTemp.EOF Then
    rstTemp.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rstTemp.EOF
      If rstTemp!strNetwork <> strNetwork Or rstTemp!strNetwork <> strNetwork Or rstTemp!strNetwork <> strNetwork Then
             strPIN = rstTemp!strPIN
         strContract = rstTemp!strContract
         strNetwork = rstTemp!strNetwork
         rst.FindFirst ("[SAP_PIN] = '" & strPIN & "' AND [Contract] = '" & strContract & "' AND [Network] = '" & strNetwork & "'")
         If Not rst.NoMatch Then
              rst.Edit
              rst!Allocated_Hrs = rstTemp!F38
              rst.Update
         End If
      Else
         rst.FindNext ("[SAP_PIN] = '" & strPIN & "' AND [Contract] = '" & strContract & "' AND [Network] = '" & strNetwork & "'")
         If Not rst.NoMatch Then
             rst.Edit
             rst!Allocated_Hrs = rstTemp!F38
             rst.Update
         End If
      End If
      rstTemp.MoveNext
   Loop
End If
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set rstTemp = Nothing
End Sub
```

i really need help thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are doing?

```sql
UPDATE qry_HR_temp_Consultant_Data_DuplicateNetwork_EachValue

INNER JOIN tbl_HR_Contract_Detail ON 
    qry_HR_temp_Consultant_Data_DuplicateNetwork_EachValue.SAP_PIN = tbl_HR_Contract_Detail.SAP_PIN
    AND qry_HR_temp_Consultant_Data_DuplicateNetwork_EachValue.Contract = tbl_HR_Contract_Detail.Contract
    AND qry_HR_temp_Consultant_Data_DuplicateNetwork_EachValue.Network = tbl_HR_Contract_Detail.Network

SET tbl_HR_Contract_Detail.Allocated_Hrs = qry_HR_temp_Consultant_Data_DuplicateNetwork_EachValue.F38;
```

You set `Allocated_Hrs`to`F38` where `SAP_PIN`,`Contract` and `Network` are equal?
`SAP_PIN`,`Contract` and `Network` are combined unique in `qry_HR_temp_Consultant_Data_DuplicateNetwork_EachValue`?

Comment: Hi im really not sure what the VB code is doing here. but i need to convert it to SQL. as i was researching, i think its quite impossible to convert it to SQL....

so right now what i am trying to do is to convert this VB code to C# ..

do you know any site that converts VB code to C#?

Comment: Did you test my answer? I'm quite confident, that it shows the same result. You can't just convert this part of code to c# and run it. You need a complete application or library what needs at least some minor coding skills. If you explain your situation, maybe there are other solutions.

Comment: Hi.. i tested it.. and it is working im not sure though if this is the expected output.. ill have to ask first... thankyou very much

Comment: also i modified it a bit and it looks like this

Comment: UPDATE tbl_HR_Contract_Detail
SET tbl_HR_Contract_Detail.Allocated_Hrs = qry_HR_temp_Consultant_Data_DuplicateNetwork_EachValue.F38
FROM qry_HR_temp_Consultant_Data_DuplicateNetwork_EachValue 
 INNER JOIN tbl_HR_Contract_Detail ON qry_HR_temp_Consultant_Data_DuplicateNetwork_EachValue.strPIN = tbl_HR_Contract_Detail.SAP_PIN
    AND qry_HR_temp_Consultant_Data_DuplicateNetwork_EachValue.strContract = tbl_HR_Contract_Detail.Contract
    AND qry_HR_temp_Consultant_Data_DuplicateNetwork_EachValue.strNetwork = tbl_HR_Contract_Detail.Network